# Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ bounded from above. Prove upper bound for $A+B$ ...

Tags: real-analysis

I've been stuck on this homework question for a while now.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ bounded from above. Prove that $A + B$ ( is bounded above and that $\sup(A+B) = \sup(A) + \sup(B)$.
>
> $A+B = \{a+b : a \in A, b\in B\}$

All I could come up with so far is:
$\max(A+B) = \max(A) + \max(B) \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$

(i.e. $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is an upper bound for $A+B$)

But, I don't know if this (i) adequately proves that $A + B$ is bounded above, and (ii) how to prove that $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is the **least** upper bound (i.e. supremum) for $A+B$.

Thanks.

Comment: For any $\epsilon \ge o$ there exist $a \in A$ such that $supA-\epsilon \le a \le supA$

Comment: What do you mean by max($A$) etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing that $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is an upper bound for $A+B$ should be straightforward, which gives the inequality $\sup(A+B) \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$.

Hence, we need to show the other half: $\sup(A) + \sup(B) \leq \sup(A+B)$. To show this, using the comment by Nilan above should be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

$\forall \epsilon >0$

1. $\exists a \in A|\sup A \geq a >\sup A-\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$
2. $\exists b \in B|\sup B \geq b >\sup B-\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$

$\therefore \forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists a\in A, b \in B |\sup A+\sup B \geq a+b \sup A + \sup B-\epsilon \implies \sup A+ \sup B= \sup (A+B)$

Answer (score 0):

First, a criticism:  the argument

> $\max(A+B) = \max(A) + \max(B) \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$

doesn't make sense in this context.  Something which you should be able to prove fairly quickly is that if a set $A$ *has* a maximum, then
$$ \sup A = \max A.$$
It is then relatively straightforward to argue that
$$ \max(A+B) = \max A + \max B $$
(as an exercise, see if you can prove this—it should be a one-liner).
So if the sets in question actually have maxima, then everything is done.  As such, not much is gained by looking at maxima, aside from the possibility that completing the exercise above might give some insight into a correct argument for suprema.

For most arguments involving the supremum (or, *mutatis mutandis*, the infimum), the key property is that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $a \in A$ such that
$$ 0 \le \sup(A) - a < \varepsilon. $$
That is, it is always possible to "squeeze" some element of $A$ into a small interval just below $A$ (and if $A$ has a maximum, take $a = \max A$).

I'll present an argument via two inequalities:

- "$\le$"  A lot of authors would probably call this result "obvious" or "clear", but I'm not a big fan of those words—this might be the easier of the two inequalities, but I think that it is worth spelling out.  Observe that if $c \in A+B$, then there are $a\in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $c = a+b$.  Hence
  $$ c = a+b \le \sup A + \sup B, $$
  which (since $c$ is arbitrary) implies that $\sup A + \sup B$ is an upper bound for $A+B$.  In other words,
  $$ \sup(A+B) \le \sup A + \sup B. \tag{$\ast$}$$
- "$\ge$"  For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist $a \in A$ and $b\in B$ such that
  $$ 0 \le \sup(A) - a < \varepsilon
  \qquad\text{and}\qquad
  0 \le \sup(B) - b < \varepsilon.^{\text{[1]}} $$
  Then
  $$ \sup(A+B)
  \ge a+b
  > \left[ \sup(A) - \varepsilon\right] + \left[ \sup(B) - \varepsilon\right]
  = \sup A + \sup B - 2\varepsilon.$$
  This holds for *any* $\varepsilon > 0$, and so
  $$ \sup(A+B) \ge \sup A + \sup B. \tag{$\ast\ast$}$$

Combining ($\ast$) and ($\ast\ast$) gives the desired result.

---

[1] A slightly more sophisticated argument is to choose $a$ and $b$ so that $\sup(A)-a < \varepsilon / 2$ and $\sup(B) - b < \varepsilon / 2$. The reason to do this is so that the result at the very end is a tidy $\varepsilon$.  However, I think that students often see these kinds of $\varepsilon/n$ arguments as a bit of a rabbit-out-of-a-hat, and so I try to present arguments more in the way that I want to think about them—I want to choose elements of $A$ and $B$ in order to make some quantity "small".  I can figure out how small later.

NB:  After writing this answer, I realized that the question is nearly a decade old (and only active because it was bumped by a new answer).  However, I don't think that any of the other answers adequately address the conflation of "maximum" and "supremum", which is a common problem that students have.  Hence I do think that this answer adds *something* to the others.  I also don't think that either of the other visible answers is very complete (there is a deleted answer which is a little better, but it was deleted by the author, and who am I to override the author's wishes?).